# Собрать .key файлы в один

Tags: безопасность, криптография, openssl, сертификат, криптопро

Есть сертификат КриптоПро:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            X_X_X
        Signature Algorithm: GOST R 34.10-2012 with GOST R 34.11-2012 (256 bit)
```

Есть (видимо) приватный ключ, состоящий из следующих файлов:

```
header.key
masks.key
masks2.key
name.key
primary.key
primary2.key
```

Вопрос: как через openssl подписать строку этим сертификатом?

Попытки:

```
openssl smime -sign -signer cert.crt -inkey key.key -engine gost -binary -noattr
```

Насколько я понял, можно так. Но для этого нужно соединить 6 ключей в один. Как это сделать? Пробовал методы в этой статье: https://habr.com/ru/post/275039/ конвертация не происходит: can not read container from F:\lp-9a0fe.000